# Why isn't this make script working?

Tags: r, macos, makefile, latex, knitr

This is the contents of `mypaper.Rnw`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{Ross Ahmed}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Header}

lorem

<<fig1>>=

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()

@
\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

I can use the `R` package `knitr` to convert `mypaper.Rnw` file to `mypaper.tex` file. I can then convert `mypaper.tex` file to `mypaper.pdf` using LaTeX.

I'm trying to do the same thing with `make`.

This is the contents of my `make` file, as provided [here](http://kbroman.org/minimal_make/)

```
mypaper.tex: R/mypaper.Rnw
    cd R;R CMD BATCH mypaper.Rnw

mypaper.pdf: mypaper.tex
    pdflatex mypaper.tex
```

If I run this in `R`:

```
system("make mypaper.pdf")
```

I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `R/mypaper.Rnw', needed by `mypaper.tex'.  Stop.
```

Where am I going wrong? I'm on a Mac OSX

Answer (score 1):

By saying:

```
mypaper.tex: R/mypaper.Rnw
```

you're saying that the file `mypaper.Rnw` lives in the `R` directory.  Does it?  You don't say it does, you just call it `mypaper.Rnw`.  If you run `ls R/mypaper.Rnw` do you get an error?

If it really is in the `R` directory, and you've not mistyped any of the names, you can run `make -r -d` to get (a lot of) debug information, and try to figure out why make is refusing to use your file.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `knitr` so I used some dummy-code to produce the files. I couldn't reproduce your error, so maybe there is some mistake in your file-structure.

I rewrote your makefile to the following which works as expected:

```
mypaper.tex: R/mypaper.Rnw
  cd R; cp mypaper.Rnw mypaper.tex

mypaper.pdf: mypaper.tex
  #cd R is needed before your command
  cd R;cp mypaper.tex mypaper.pdf
```

File-structure before:

```
.
├── makefile
└── R
    └── mypaper.Rnw
```

File-structure after:

```
.
├── makefile
└── R
    ├── mypaper.pdf
    ├── mypaper.Rnw
    └── mypaper.tex
```